# Android Contacts not working with custom account_type on all contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I m trying implement code to show my application in native Contacts app like WhatsApp, Skype and other calling app. So user can user my application instead of native Dialer app. I tried to implement [Custom SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter) to update contacts with my application. Custom sync adapter worked fine but my application name shows under randomly contacts( not in all contacts). So I need help in

1. How all native contacts show my application name ?
2. If my application name appeared on native contact and try to select number to dial with my app, shows error toast message "No application found to handle this action". Even after setting correct MIME type.

I have tested on Android 8.1 and Android 12

Comment: post your code so we can check what can be fixed

Comment: I found the root cause for issue. It was due to manifest package name and project package different. Contacts not able to identify valid class path.